# Is it possible to call a SOAP Service from WebAPI Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, soap

I would like to know, is it commonly possible to call SOAP Services from WebAPI Service?

I have a Project on the basis of WebAPI (EntryPoints Project) also I have a Legacy Framework with SOAP Services. 
I want to upload a file to the Legacy Framework Repository (i.e. all Services of the FW are already tested and successfully used in another projects), but through an EntryPoint Project, which is connected to my FrontEnd (JS).

A Workflow looks like following process:

1. A File must be loaded in directory of EntryPoint Project.
2. If the file is loaded (WebAPI Service of EntryPoint is still in
   use), the SOAP Service must be started and this File is loading to its   Repository.

But if I try to **read** (sic!) the file from the EntryPoint Directory I've got an Exception: Another Process blocks the File. I have used a "Handle.exe" Program to recognize a blocking Process and it is a Process "iisexpress". This is an EntryPoint application process.

Hier is a code in an EntryPoint Project (I have tried to make the code more understandable):

```
try
   {
     int fileId = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
         {
            // Upload a file to temporary directory of EntryPoint Project
            Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            string fileName = provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName;
            return fileName;
         }
         , CancellationToken.None,
         TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
         TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
     .ContinueWith<int>(fileTask =>
         {
            string filePath = fileTask.Result;
            // Exception is thrown on the next line
            int ident = clientOfLegacyFramework.UploadFileToRepositoryAndSaveItInDB(filePath);
            ...
            return ident;
         }
         , CancellationToken.None
         , TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning
           | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent
           | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
           , TaskScheduler.Default);

     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileId);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
   }
```